# comparing two time values with 2 column respectively after converting in 24 hour format

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two varchar column with time values store in 12 hour format. I want to get the output like rows that which don't fall in 10:00 am to 12:00 pm

here

```
id  |time1     | time2
____|__________|__________
1   |01:00 pm  | 10:00 pm
2   |11:00 am  | 01:00 pm
3   |09:00 am  | 11:00 am
4   |05:00 pm  | 11:59 pm
```

output will be

```
1   |01:00 pm  | 10:00 pm
4   |05:00 pm  | 11:59 pm
```

here is the link of sqlfiddle to test
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6bf48/2

Comment: Why are you storing times in a `varchar` column and not in a column of type `time`

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: I am using VARCHAR so that i can easily cross check from phpmyadmin with the values from website. If I user TIME then it shows seconds and milliseconds too. I will have to convert those every time in 12 hour format wherever i will have to display it.

Comment: @dwk279 over time you're going to find it's much easier to change the display format of a date/time column than it is to perform date/time operations (eg, comparisons, math) on strings

Comment: Show us the "convert" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example output I'm assuming the requirement is to display rows where the time1-time2 range falls completely outside of the desired 10:00am-12:00pm range.

Assumption:

- `time2 >= time1`

This is going to be easier if we convert the strings to times and let the database do the time comparisons for us.

In MySQL we can convert the given strings to (date)times via the following construct:

- `str_to_date(<string_value>,'%h:%i %p')`

The rows we're looking for should match one of the following tests:

- `time1 > 12:00 pm`
- `time2 < 10:00 am`

One possible solution:

```
select time1,
       time2
from   splash
where  str_to_date(time1,'%h:%i %p') > str_to_date('12:00 pm','%h:%i %p')
or     str_to_date(time2,'%h:%i %p') < str_to_date('10:00 am','%h:%i %p')
order by 1,2;

time1      time2
========   ========
01:00 pm   10:00 pm
05:00 pm   11:59 pm
```

Was having some timeout issues with the OPs fiddle so here's a [rextester fiddle](http://rextester.com/NIIO93535) for the above solution.